# Why String behaves like value type while using ==

Tags: c#, .net

want to know why String  behaves like value type while using ==.

```
         String s1 = "Hello";
        String s2 = "Hello";
        Console.WriteLine(s1 == s2);// True(why? s1 and s2 are different)
        Console.WriteLine(s1.Equals(s2));//True
        StringBuilder a1 = new StringBuilder("Hi");
        StringBuilder a2 = new StringBuilder("Hi");
        Console.WriteLine(a1 == a2);//false
        Console.WriteLine(a1.Equals(a2));//true
```

StringBuilder and String behaves differently with == operator. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Two different reasons;

- interning - since the `"Hello"` string(s) are compiled into the source, they **are** the same reference - check `ReferenceEquals(s1,s2)` - it will return `true`
- custom equality - string has equality operators (in particular, `==` / `!=` (aka `op_Equality` / `op_Inequality`)

The `StringBuilder` version fails because:

- they **aren't** the same reference (these are regular managed objects created separately on the managed heap)
- `StringBuilder` doesn't have the operators

Call `ToString()` on each, and it gets more interesting:

- the two strings **aren't** the same reference
- but the operator support guarantees a `true`

Answer (score 8):

The `==` operator is overloaded in the `String` class, in a way that makes the string values to be compared instead of the object references, which is the default.

Answer (score 3):

Because == operator is redefined for strings.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664728(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's because the equality operator has been overridden to provide the functionality you see. You can do this on any type by overriding the equals operator.

Answer (score -2):

Using == for strings is bad practice anyways, just use Equals().

[Details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664728%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: And why does that make == bad practice? Internally, `==` just calls `string.Equals(a,b)`; I find `==` clearer. The only side-case here is when one param is typed as `object` - is that the issue you are trying to highlight?

Comment: No thanks. One of the thing I really hate when moving from C# to Java is having to use Equals to compare strings. Believe it or not, but == is more readable.

Comment: I think equals is only useful if you want to use one of the StringComparison enum's values.